# Creating dict from .csv with duplicate rows from one column as value for keys from adjacent column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have a simple .csv with 9 rows and 2 columns.

[image: csv]

The "lat" column has unique data and "lon" column has duplicate data,

I am struggling to convert into a dict with key being column "lon" and values being from column "lat" but if they are duplicates then the values have to be put together in a list. so something like this

```
newdict = {1:['A'],2:['B','C','D'],3:['E','F','G'],8:['H']}
```

I actually coded it at work but now I am at home god knows why , I cannot recreate it , Been struggling on this for 3 days.

I would add my code here but its wrong and i know it , i do not want to mislead other readers into some gibberish in my head.

Comment: `df.groupby('lon')['lat'].apply(list).to_dict()`?

Comment: @Yo_Chris add it as an answer so it can be checked, otherwise someone will just copy and add your comment as their answer.

Comment: @Yo_Chris Woah! , and i was using for loops. Update it as an answer man I will accept it. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Just an FYI, if you're using pandas and find yourself using loops, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Ahh, I see, thanks for the tip. should probably learn more pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat': list('abcdefg'), 'lon': [1,2,2,2,3,3,4]})
# groupby lon, apply list to lat and then to_dict
df.groupby('lon')['lat'].apply(list).to_dict()

# {1: ['a'], 2: ['b', 'c', 'd'], 3: ['e', 'f'], 4: ['g']}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv
new_dict = {}
filepath = "/path/to/latlon.csv"

with open(filepath, newline='') as f:
    # skip the csv's header row
    next(f) 

    rows = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for lat, lon in rows:
        if lon in new_dict:
            new_dict[lon].append(lat)
        else:
            new_dict[lon] = [lat]
```

Output:

```
{'1': ['A'], '2': ['B', 'C', 'D'], '3': ['E', 'F', 'G'], '8': ['H']}
```